# How to get current path of a dll

Tags: .net, visual-c++

In my C# application we are using a dll that is in vc++,we want to know the curent path of that dll in vc++,

Comment: Maybe one of these will help:  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686944(v=vs.85).aspx)   (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get the location from C# you could use reflection and the [GetAssembly(Type type) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getassembly.aspx#Y0)

In C++

```
Assembly^ SampleAssembly;
// Instantiate a target object. Int32 Integer1(0); Type^ Type1; 
// Set the Type instance to the target class type. 
Type1 = Integer1.GetType();
// Instantiate an Assembly class to the assembly housing the Integer type.
SampleAssembly = Assembly::GetAssembly( Integer1.GetType() );
// Gets the location of the assembly using file: protocol.
Console::WriteLine("CodeBase= {0}", SampleAssembly->CodeBase);
```

Or from your calling C# code just replace Integer1, with a type from your VC++ assembly.